# Tokbox screenshare issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, tokbox, screensharing

I am using `session.unpublish(Publisher)` to stop screen share and then republish video stream publisher to start video publisher, but next time when I start screen share it creates problems.

In tokbox js what is the best way to stop screen share.

Actually I have two publisher when screenshare is on AudioVideoPublisher and ScreenPublisher both in different container as screenshare does not publish Audio with screen so I have also need AudioVideoPublisher in that case.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to stop the publishing is to call unpublish like you're doing but then it's best to wait for the streamDestroyed event before you publish again. eg.

```
publisher.on('streamDestroyed', function(event) {
  // publish again
  var publisher = OT.initPublisher();
  session.publish(publisher);
});
session.unpublish(publisher);
```

Comment: Screenshare popup not close when I stop screenshare using session.unpublish(screenPublisher)

Comment: Which popup are you referring to? The one that pops up and asks you to pick which screen to share? You're right, that doesn't go away when you unpublish. The user will have to click the cancel button on that as well. Seems like a bug in Chrome actually, you might want to file one https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list