# How to detect publishVideo(false) in OpenTok screenshare subscriber

Tags: angular, opentok, tokbox

I'm subscribing to an screen sharing stream as follows:

```
this.openTokSession.on('streamCreated', (event: any) => {
    if(event.stream.videoType === 'screen') {
        //it's screen sharing
        var screenSubscriber = this.openTokSession.subscribe(event.stream, 
            'screenshareDisplay', {
                appendMode: 'append',
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%'
                },
            (error: any) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                    screenSubscriber.on("videoDisabled", (event: any) => {
                        console.log('videoDisabled1')
                    });  
                }
            }
        );
    } else {
        //it's normal video
    }
});
```

You'll see that I'm attempting to listen to `videoDisabled` on the subscriber above, but have also tried it on the session here:

```
this.openTokSession.on("videoDisabled", (event: any) => {
    console.log('videoDisabled1')
    if(typeof(event.stream) !== 'undefined') {
        if(event.stream.videoType === 'screen') {
            console.log('videoDisabled2');
            }
        }
    });
```

...but neither event fires, despite the fact that I can see the screen share stop when the publisher calls `publishVideo(false)`.

Can anyone give me any pointers to which event I should be listening for, and whether it's on the stream or the session?

EDIT in response to @Manik's post

It looks as if publishVideo(false) does cause a videoDisabled event to be available on the subscriber IF the videoType is a camera, but not if the videoType is screen:

In the same application (the same session), I also have:

```
var subscriberProperties = {
    insertMode: 'append', 
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
};    
var subscriber = this.openTokSession.subscribe(event.stream,
    subscriberDivId,
    subscriberProperties,
    (error: any) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            subscriber.on('videoDisabled', (event: any) => {
                console.log('videoDisabled');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

...and when I publishVideo(false) on the publisher for the camera, it does indeed cause a videoDisabled event in the subscriber to that stream.

My current thinking is either that there's a bug in the screen share stream event firing or that, maybe, publishVideo(false) is not appropriate for a screen share stream.

The next thing I am going to try is this: [Tokbox screenshare issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46558434/tokbox-screenshare-issue) ie unpublishing on the session to see if that produces an event I *can* handle.

EDIT 2: For anyone else struggling with this, didn't solve the original problem - my bad coding or unexpected behaviour with TokBox - but did get subscriber to respond to stopping and starting screen sharing as follows:

As before:

```
this.openTokSession.on('streamCreated', (event: any) => {
    if(event.stream.videoType === 'screen') {
        //it's screen sharing, pop it into the lh panel
        var screenSubscriberProperties = {
            insertMode: 'append', 
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%'
        };
        var screenSubscriber = this.openTokSession.subscribe(event.stream, 
            'screenshareDisplay', 
            screenSubscriberProperties,
            (error: any) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                    //code to rearrange UI
                }
            }
        );
    } else {
    }
```

But then on the publisher, instead of `publishVideo(false)`, actually unpublish:

```
this.openTokSession.unpublish(this.screenSharingPublisher);
```

And then listen for this event:

```
    this.openTokSession.on("streamDestroyed", (event:any) => {
        if(typeof(event.stream) !== 'undefined') {
            if(event.stream.videoType === 'screen') {
                //code to rearrange UI
                if (event.reason === 'mediaStopped') {
                    // User clicked stop sharing
                } else if (event.reason === 'forceUnpublished') {
                    // A moderator forced the user to stop sharing.
                }    
            } else {
                //deal with unpublished camera stream
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

As a subscriber, to know when the video of a stream has been disabled, you should listen to the [`videoDisabled`](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Subscriber.html#events) event on the subscriber object.

It looks like you're setting the event listener on the subscriber object inside the callback which is why the event is not firing. You should have something like this outside the callback function:

```
subscriber.on('videoDisabled', event => {
   console.log('video disabled ', event);
});
```

Please note that the `session.subscribe` method takes a callback function so you can know if there was a synchronous error while subscribing, but regardless of the error, the method will still return a subscriber object.

Comment: Thanks @Manik - I'll give this a try this evening, although have a feeling that I tried it outside the callback function as well but maybe the screenSubscriber reference was no longer in scope...

Comment: I'm afraid that's still not working - putting the screenSubscriber event listener just below and outside the var screenSubscriber statement - any clues for debugging what's going wrong e.g some way of seeing which events are being fired?

Comment: Could it make any difference that I also have a normal camera stream running at the same time?

Comment: @theotherdy I'm not sure why that's not working for you. Can you check out the following sample code and see if it works for you?
https://jsfiddle.net/jkmo7svn/2/

Comment: Thanks @Manik. I'm wondering whether not firing a videoDisabled event is specific to a screen video source? I already have code in my application that successfully listens to audioLevelUpdated on a camera subscriber. I'm keen to get on with this - is there any method I can call on the publisher to stop screen sharing which will fire an event on the session instead of the stream?

Comment: @theotherdy Apologies for the delay - it looks like this is a bug in the SDK. I've relayed this to the team and will update you once this is fixed. To clarify, this is only happening for when the stream's video source is the screen.